# Config apartment-gem for MySQL using structure.sql instead of schema.rb to create a new tenant

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, apartment-gem

I need View SQL and Stored Procedure in my Rails app so I have to change from schema.rb to structure.sql. This is my config in `config/application.rb`

```
config.active_record.schema_format = :sql
```

but then when I create a new record for an entity in seed.rb

```
Company.create(
        name: 'Google',
        subdomain: 'google'
      )
```

error happened

> my_project/db/schema.rb doesn't exist yet

I don't know what is the problem. Did I miss something in cofig, somewhere still require schema.rb or I miss some rake task command? I just used

```
rake db:migrate db:test:prepare
```

follow this blog https://rietta.com/blog/2013/11/28/rails-and-sql-views-for-a-report/#setting-up-the-sql-view

UPDATE: 
I am using `apartment-gem` and `Company` entity is a Tenant.

Here is config in `apartment.rb`

```
Apartment.configure do |config|
  config.excluded_models = %w{ Company CommonField }
  config.tenant_names = lambda{ Company.pluck(:subdomain) }
  # ==> PostgreSQL only options
  config.use_schemas = true

  # Apartment can be forced to use raw SQL dumps instead of schema.rb for 
  # creating new schemas.
  # Use this when you are using some extra features in PostgreSQL that can't 
  # be respresented in
  # schema.rb, like materialized views etc. (only applies with use_schemas set 
  # to true).
  # (Note: this option doesn't use db/structure.sql, it creates SQL dump by 
  # executing pg_dump)
  #
  # config.use_sql = false
  # <== PostgreSQL only options
  config.prepend_environment = !Rails.env.production?
end
```

I try to change `config.use_schemas`  to `false` then enable and set `config.use_sql` to `true` but it still not work. Maybe it's setting for PosrtgreSQL only.

So, have any setting for MySQL?

Comment: Could you provide the full error stack trace?

Answer (score 1):

the `mysql2_adapter` in gem `apartment` extend from `abstract_adapter` and it inherits the [create method](https://github.com/influitive/apartment/blob/development/lib/apartment/adapters/abstract_adapter.rb#L20-L33) as below:

```rb
def create(tenant)
 run_callbacks :create do
  create_tenant(tenant)

  switch(tenant) do
   import_database_schema

   # Seed data if appropriate
   seed_data if Apartment.seed_after_create

   yield if block_given?
  end
 end
end
```

the `import_database_schema` method will throw the error: `FileNotFound ... db/schema.rb doesn't exist yet` if there's no such file `schema.rb`, so i guess when you decide to use `structure.sql` instead of `schema.rb` you deleted it.

i suggest 2 ways to fix:

1. create an empty file `schema.rb`, that it.
2. you still need the config `use_schemas` since that indicate gem `apartment` will use `postgresql schemas` and `mysql use`, however
   in case of `mysql`, if you use `structure.sql`, no need to `import_database_schema` at all, right ? so you can create new mysql adapter like below:

```rb
# your-app/lib/apartment/adapters/mysql2_structure_adapter.rb
require 'apartment/adapters/mysql2_adapter'

module Apartment
  module Tenant
    def self.mysql2_adapter(config)
      if Apartment.use_schemas
        Apartment.use_sql ?
          Adapters::Mysql2StructureAdapter.new(config) :
          Adapters::Mysql2SchemaAdapter.new(config)
      else
        Adapters::Mysql2Adapter.new(config)
      end
    end
  end

  module Adapters
    class Mysql2StructureAdapter < Mysql2SchemaAdapter
      def create(tenant)
        run_callbacks :create do
          create_tenant(tenant)

          switch(tenant) do
            # no need to import schema
            # import_database_schema

            # Seed data if appropriate
            seed_data if Apartment.seed_after_create

            yield if block_given?
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

then load that adapter, also turn on both `use_schemas` and `use_sql` on initializer config

```rb
# config/initializers/apartment.rb
Apartment.configure do |config|
  # ...
  config.use_schemas = true
  config.use_sql = true
end
# ...
Dir[File.join(Rails.root, "lib", "apartment", "adapters", "**/*.rb")].each {|r| require r}
```